# Can any 1st-order proof be expressed with an SMT?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, satisfiability, automated-theorem-proving

Is it possible to rephrase every proof which uses first-order logic into a proof which uses satisfiability modulo theories? In other words, can a program which automatically solves SMT questions solve every first-order proof based on decidable theories as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's slightly unclear to me what you're asking here, but I believe it's the following:

> **Question:** Let $Sat$ be the problem of telling whether a sentence $p$ is satisfiable relative to a c.e. theory $T$, and *Prove* be the problem of telling whether a sentence $p$ is provable from a c.e. theory $T$. Is $Prove$ "reducible" to $Sat$?

*Note that by [Craig's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Craig%27s_theorem), the c.e. axiomatizable theories are exactly the computably axiomatizable theories.*

The answer depends on exactly what "reducible" means in this case. There are two natural notions here: **many-one** and **Turing**. The first says "no" and the second says "yes."

Specifically, the key fact is this:

> **[Completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem) (special case):** A sentence $p$ is satisfiable relative to a c.e. theory $T$ iff $\neg p$ is not provable relative to $T$.

The transformation $p\mapsto \neg p$ is clearly computable, so the only potential issue is whether the switch from "is **in**" to "is **not in**" - that is, whether we're allowed to exchange *positive* $Sat$-information for *negative* $Prove$-information. Turing reductions do allow this, while many-one reductions don't.

*(Strictly speaking, the statement above just shows that the map $p\mapsto\neg p$ doesn't yield a many-one reduction, and doesn't rule out the possibility of a non-obvious many-one reduction between $Sat$ and $Prove$. But we can indeed prove that none exists - this follows e.g. from the fact that $Prove$ is c.e. but not computable.)*

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! There are several things here which I don't fully understand. Does this mean that there is no way to turn every instance of _Prove_ into an instance of _Sat_, but that there is an algorithm which would use the result of _Sat_ to give an answer to _Prove_?